# Trouble Implementing Two-way Binding with Custom Telerik Numerical Textbox Component in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, telerik

I am having difficulty implementing a custom Telerik Numerical Textbox component in a Blazor application, specifically with setting up two-way data binding.

In my Razor page, I'm trying to use the custom component like so:

```
<CustomNumericalTextBox Id="ID" Format="P" Min="0" Max="1" Step="0.01m" @Bind-Value="@Model.Value1" />
```

In the code-behind of this page, I have a model:

```
public class Model 
{
    public decimal Value1 { get; set; } = "Something"
}
```

The custom component is defined in a separate Razor page:

```
@inherits CustomNumericalTextBoxBase

<FormItem>
    <Template>
        <TelerikNumericalTextBox Id="@Id" Format="@Format" Min="@Min" Max="@Max" @bind-Value="@BindValue">
        </TelerikNumericalTextBox>
    </Template>
</FormItem>
```

And its code-behind is:

```
public class CustomNumericalTextBox 
{
    [Parameter]
    public decimal BindValue { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<decimal> BindValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Format { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter]
    public string Min { get; set; } = "0";

    [Parameter]
    public string Max { get; set; } = "1";

    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Any guidance on how I can achieve two-way data binding with this custom component would be greatly appreciated.

The errors I receive are:

- 'CustomNumericalTextBox.BuildRederTree(RederTreeBuilder)': No suitable method found to override
- 'CustomNumericalTextBox.BuildRederTree(RederTreeBuilder)': No suitable method found to override
- The attribute names could not be inferred from bind attribute 'bind-BindValue'. Bind attributes should be of the form 'bind' or 'bind-value' along with their corresponding optional parameters like 'bind-value:event', 'bind:format' etc.

Comment: i would suggest to check if your references are correct, if you instantiated another control that was using an old dll, you will have this mismatches, i have had similar problems with telerik for wpf

Answer (score 0):

You code doesn't quite add up, but your issue is that you can't just pass binds through.

This:

```cs
<TelerikNumericalTextBox .... @bind-Value="@BindValue">
```

Won't work.  It will just update `BindValue`, not call `BindValueChanged`.

You need to manually wire up the bind gets and sets.

I don't use Telerik.  It costs me money to have it installed and answer questions on it for free!

However, the controls work in a similar manner to the standard input controls, so the same rules apply.

Demo using standard `InputNumber`

```cs
@using System.Linq.Expressions;

<InputNumber @bind-Value:get=this.Value @bind-Value:set=this.OnValueChanged />

@code {
    [Parameter] public decimal? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<decimal?> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<decimal?>>? ValueExpression { get; set; }

    private async Task OnValueChanged(decimal? value)
    {
        await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}
```

And page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<NumericTextBox @bind-Value=value />

<div class="m-3">Value : @value </div>

@code {
    decimal? value = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help! Unfortunately, this gave me several errors:

- The type arguments for method 'TypeInference.CreateTelerikNumericTextBox_0<T>(RenderTreeBuilder, int, int, string, int, string, int, T, int, T, int, T, int, int, int, bool, int, T, int, EventCallback<T>, int, Expression<Func<T>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. 

- Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Comment: - Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<decimal>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback

Comment: Try setting `TValue` on the control to `decimal?` `<TelerikNumericTextBox .... TType="decimal?" ,,,>.  My free usage of the controls ran out a long while ago.  It's one of the problems on here with using paid for libraries.  Most of us [people who answer questions] don't use them!  Also try doing everythnig with a `decimal` rather than the nullable  `decimal?`

Comment: This didn't work either. Also, we found out that we can inherit inputbase<string> on our page containing the numerical text box, but it didn't work either.....

Comment: You'll have to ask Telerik.